# That calling tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath did not show a check mark on the cell in edit mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

It is a table view in edit mode in the picture.

> In the table view, if I touch a cell, check mark will appear.
>   I want to select all cells when user clicked "Select All".

```
for index in 0..<skus.count{
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:index,inSection:0)
            self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath , animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)
        }
```

> Here problem comes. After I cliked "Select All", there are no check mark appear, and the two check marks will disappear.What happened? How to solve it?

Comment: What does the code look like for drawing the checkmarks? You'll probably want to have a switch when you draw the checkmarks that accounts for a cell having a checkmark and not having a checkmark.

Comment: do you update your data source?

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer.

In edit mode just like above, check mark will appear automatic if you called `tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath( animated: scrollPosition: )` , but if you called `tableView.reloadData()` after that, all check marks will disappear and you will get nothing when you call `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()`.

> Here is the description about `tabieView.reloadData()` :
>
> 'Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on.'
>
> So, as we know, this method will clear all of the data and back to the beginning status, the table view will be drawn again with the data source.
>
> > Tips: It is a pretty dangerous action that calling `reloadData` in some case.

Comment: But that's _not_ the answer. — The answer is that you should be storing the checked status of each row _in your data model_, and _using_ that checked status as part of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation. That way, `reloadData()` works fine.

Comment: These check marks are drawn by system, not me. You will enter editing mode if you call `tableView.editing = true` and `tableView.allowMutipleSelectionDuringEditingMode = true`. Check marks appear next to selected rows in editing mode automatic when you touch the cell or call `tableView.selectRowForIndexPath` manually.

Comment: My problem is that why there is no check mark appears after I called `tableView.selectRowForIndexPath` . I found the reason is that I called `tableView.reloadData()` after I called `tableView.selectRowForIndexPath`, so , in fact, the check mark appears, but disappears immediately, I can't see it. Thank for your comment, matt, my english is pretty terrible, sorry for it and thank you. :)